# Error while installing puppet-agent on SLES 11

Tags: puppet, suse, puppet-enterprise, sles

I'm evaluating Puppet Enterprise 2015.2, didn't have any problem until I've tried to install the agent on a SLES 11 box.

I've followed the procedure above:

1 - Added class pe_repo::platform::sles_11_x86_64 to PE Master group on PE Console

2 - Executed curl from the client:

`curl -k https://myserver:8140/packages/current/install.bash | sudo bash`

The command log:

```
 % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100 14657  100 14657    0     0   117k      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:-- 4771k
Removing repository 'puppet-enterprise' [done]
Repository 'puppet-enterprise' has been removed.
Adding repository 'puppet-enterprise' [done]
Repository 'puppet-enterprise' successfully added
Enabled: Yes
Autorefresh: No
URI: https://myserver:8140/packages/2015.2.1/sles-11-x86_64?ssl_verify=no

Retrieving repository 'puppet-enterprise' metadata [done]
Building repository 'puppet-enterprise' cache [done]
Specified repositories have been refreshed.
**Unknown option '--from'**
Loading repository data...
Reading installed packages...
**'puppet-agent' not found.**
/tmp/tmp.SVlCxPXa7e: line 91: /opt/puppetlabs/puppet/bin/puppet: No such file or directory
[main]
/tmp/tmp.SVlCxPXa7e: line 100: /opt/puppetlabs/puppet/bin/puppet: No such file or directory
/tmp/tmp.SVlCxPXa7e: line 113: /opt/puppetlabs/puppet/bin/facter: No such file or directory
/tmp/tmp.SVlCxPXa7e: line 113: /opt/puppetlabs/puppet/bin/ruby: No such file or directory
/tmp/tmp.SVlCxPXa7e: line 113: /opt/puppetlabs/puppet/bin/puppet: No such file or directory
/tmp/tmp.SVlCxPXa7e: line 122: /opt/puppetlabs/puppet/bin/puppet: No such file or directory
/tmp/tmp.SVlCxPXa7e: line 123: /opt/puppetlabs/puppet/bin/puppet: No such file or directory
/tmp/tmp.SVlCxPXa7e: line 127: /opt/puppetlabs/puppet/bin/puppet: No such file or directory
/tmp/tmp.SVlCxPXa7e: line 62: /opt/puppetlabs/puppet/bin/puppet: No such file or directory
/tmp/tmp.SVlCxPXa7e: line 62: /opt/puppetlabs/puppet/bin/puppet: No such file or directory
/tmp/tmp.SVlCxPXa7e: line 62: /opt/puppetlabs/puppet/bin/puppet: No such file or directory
/tmp/tmp.SVlCxPXa7e: line 62: /opt/puppetlabs/puppet/bin/puppet: No such file or directory
Error running install script /tmp/tmp.SVlCxPXa7e
```

First note on script line 217:

`zypper --non-interactive dist-upgrade --from puppet-enterprise`

`--from` wasn't accepted as a valid argument. maybe the correct was '-r'?

Second note: The script didn't installed puppet-agent so I've tried to install it pushing the file puppet-agent-1.2.5-1.sles11.x86_64.rpm to the client and after that running a zypper in puppet-agent

With this workaround I was able to install the agent, then I ran the script again and got a problem with libfacter:

```
curl -k https://myserver:8140/packages/current/install.bash | sudo bash
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100 14657  100 14657    0     0   153k      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:-- 13.9M
Removing repository 'puppet-enterprise' [done]
Repository 'puppet-enterprise' has been removed.
Adding repository 'puppet-enterprise' [done]
Repository 'puppet-enterprise' successfully added
Enabled: Yes
Autorefresh: No
URI: https://myserver:8140/packages/2015.2.1/sles-11-x86_64?ssl_verify=no

Retrieving repository 'puppet-enterprise' metadata [done]
Building repository 'puppet-enterprise' cache [done]
Specified repositories have been refreshed.
**Unknown option '--from'**
Loading repository data...
Reading installed packages...
**'puppet-agent' is already installed.**
Resolving package dependencies...
Nothing to do.
**libfacter was not found. Please make sure it was installed to the expected location.
libfacter was not found. Please make sure it was installed to the expected location.
libfacter was not found. Please make sure it was installed to the expected location.
libfacter was not found. Please make sure it was installed to the expected location.**
Error running install script /tmp/tmp.GDlmNNh07V
```

**EDIT 1**: It appears that it only happens on SLES 11 SP1. I've tested on SLES 11 SP3 and it's working.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately the `libfacter was not found. Please make sure it was installed to the expected location.` error message is bogus. For me the real problem was that I had my `LC_NAME` environment variable set to a locale which was not available on the puppet machine. After running `unset LC_NAME` puppet started working. (I know it's bizarre, but I can reliably reproduce it.)

So first try `unset LC_NAME`, if that doesn't help run `strace -e file -f puppet`, that's what helped me nail down the problem.

Comment: Could you please file a bug report about this issue?

Comment: Unfortunately, this didn't work for me! I appreciate your help Tobias!